# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [node && vagrant]

Tags: node.js, dns, vagrant

Im running a node app inside a vagrant box. The code itself is shared to the host machine, same as the ports in which the app runs.

The app runs OK, until some point in which it send this warning, and cancelling the request in progress.

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)`

I've copied this request as CURL, and excecuted outside & inside the VM box, and the result is the same. Also, I've check that the VM has internet access.

Node version is 10.33, but I also have tryied 10.32. I've have the same error with Ubuntu1204, Ubuntu1404, Ubuntu1410, CentOs65.

Same code on my previous environment worked OK. I dont think this is a code-related issue, but issue w/ environment shared folders or permissions

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Apparently, the app was heading to some URL that I have previously deleted. My bad, closing this

Comment: I saw those errors too yesterday in a vagrant / VirtualBox VM. Are those node.js files in a shared folder? Do you host those VMs on a Windows Host?

Comment: Yes, shared folder, but not on a Windows host. Im on a Mac with Yosemite

Comment: Is this a local hostname?  There are a few things that can cause that message, such as an mis-edited /etc/hosts file, or /etc/resolv.conf file (i.e. DNS hostname not right) in combination with a misconfigured nameserver.  Can you give a little more information on the actual URL that's failing?

Comment: Yes, its a local hostname. The /etc/hosts file is blank. Regarding the URL thats failing, its a URL that triggers a connection to an external service (from the backend). I guess that the problem is during this request.

Comment: I'm not sure if on a mac is the same bug however try to run the node.js files in the VM only without a shared folder.

Comment: Thats a good try, @rekire. Unfortunately, I have done this yesterday, and the error was the same. Im gonna try this again in a while

Comment: Hello juanmatt, did you have any luck with this? I'm experimenting something similar.